# React re-renders even with no change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

We have set up a project with redux. In this project, we get an info objecat from an api and insert it into the store. Now we noticed that the function components re-render even if the api return the same state as in the previous request.

We think it's because we are overwriting the store but we are not sure.

ChatContainer.js

```js
const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {
    content: state.info.content,
    loading: state.info.loading,
  }
}

const ChatContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Chat)
export default ChatContainer
```

Chat.js

```js
function Chat(props) {

    const { content, loading } = props;
    return (
        <Info content={content} loading={loading} />
    ) 
}
```

action.js

```
export function setInfo(info) {
  return {
    type: SET_INFO, info: {
      content: info,
      loading: false
    }
  }
}
```

reducer.js

```js
function setInfo(state = { content: [], loading: true }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INFO:
      return action.info
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({
...
  info: setInfo,
...
})
export default appReducer
```

Comment: Apparently, either content or loading is changing, but we can't tell without seeing the code. Please show us the reducer and how you're dispatching the action.

Comment: The `loading` can toggle but this happens only on first read. Every continuous read uses the same action. (see `setInfo()`)

Comment: "We think it's because we are overwriting the store but we are not sure." Share the code of your reducer.

Comment: Do a check before dispatching an action / setting state - rerender happens even if data is the same. React is not that clever as you may think - check data if it changed.and than do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If state.info.content is an object, every time you change it with setInfo it will have a new reference. React-redux does a shallow compare on the result of mapStateToProps, so if your content is a different reference every time your component will re-render. connect HOC has an options parameter that you can use to implement a custom compare.

My advice would be to add a check to your setInfo or to the code calling setInfo and not calling your API if data is already loaded/didn't change(don't know your business logic).